# ORA-01654: unable to extend index

Tags: java, oracle, cluster-computing

Calling all Oracle Gurus!

I am in the process of clustering a well tested application on WebSphere. The application in question made it about half way through processing 1k of JMS messages from a queue before this happened.

```
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01654: unable to extend index DABUAT.INDEX1 by 128 in tablespace DABUAT_TBLSP

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
```

I have had a quick look online and found a few possible suggestions as to why this could have happend,  if anyone could give a clear explanation as to why this may have occurred now my application has been clusterd I would be most grateful.

Regards Karl

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are out of disk space.

Increase your `TABLESPACE`:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE DABUAT_TBLSP
ADD DATAFILE 'C:\FolderWithPlentyOfSpace\DABUAT_TBLSP001.DBF' 
SIZE 4M
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 4M
MAXSIZE 64G;

-- Put your own size parameters here
```

Comment: How to select the current DATAFILES?

Comment: select * from v$datafile;

Comment: while MAXSIZE 64G stands for 64 Giga bytes, so always add less than your current free size, else it will give the same error.

Comment: Hi, I am getting following error for this. java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01654: unable to extend index ODM_DSI.EVENTSTORE_IDX2 by 1024 in tablespace USERS. will extending tablespace will again help here?

Comment: @PranavNath worth a try

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using ASM then you can add with below comment

you can run below command to get size of datafile

```
SELECT
    file_name,
    bytes / 1024 / 1024 mb
FROM
    dba_data_files
WHERE
    tablespace_name = 'APP_DATA'
ORDER BY
    file_name;


FILE_NAME mb
------------------------------------------------------------ -------
+DATA/SID/datafile/app_data.dbf 20000
+DATA/SID/datafile/app_data.dbf 28100
```

Resizing and adding

```
+DATA/path/indx_operational_00.dbf

alter database datafile '+DATA/path/indx_operational_00.dbf' resize 3000m;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question having same error migrating small subset of large database into test database in Docker.

In my case the problem was simply in using system tablespace for user tables, which was default setup in Oracle image. After creating custom tablespace using command

```
create tablespace mytablespace datafile '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE/mytablespace.dbf' size 500M autoextend on next 250M maxsize 10G;`
```

(as well as creating all tables and indexes in that tablespace) the problem disappeared. No special fiddling with datafiles was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**ERROR: In Alertlog**

ORA-1654: unable to extend index PRODADM.XT021S1 by 128 in tablespace PROD_01
2024-03-23T16:26:11.156475+05:30

ORA-1654: unable to extend index PRODADM.XT021S1 by 128 in tablespace PROD_01
2024-03-23T16:26:19.194628+05:30

**TROUBLESHOOTING STEPS:**

**

- Track all Tablespaces with free space < 10%

**

```
Select a.tablespace_name,sum(a.tots/1048576) Tot_Size, sum(a.sumb/1024) Tot_Free, sum(a.sumb)*100/sum(a.tots) Pct_Free, ceil((((sum(a.tots) * 15) - (sum(a.sumb)*100))/85 )/1048576) Min_Add
from (select tablespace_name,0 tots,sum(bytes) sumb
from dba_free_space a
group by tablespace_name
union
Select tablespace_name,sum(bytes) tots,0 from dba_data_files
group by tablespace_name) a group by a.tablespace_name
having sum(a.sumb)*100/sum(a.tots) < 10
order by pct_free;  


TABLESPACE_NAME                  TOT_SIZE   TOT_FREE   PCT_FREE    MIN_ADD
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
PROD_01                       131071.938          0          0      23131
```

Space is completely filled up,hence throwing above error in alert log and application team unable to perform Insert operation .

**CHECK THE DATAFILE LOCATION IN DISKGROUP.**

```
select FILE_NAME,FILE_ID,TABLESPACE_NAME,BYTES/1024/1024 from dba_data_files where TABLESPACE_NAME='PROD_01';

FILE_NAME                         FILE_ID TABLESPACE_NAME                BYTES/1024/1024
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------ ---------------
+DATA/SID/DATAFILE/PROD_01          2 PROD_01                            32767.9844
.281.1133447489

+DATA/SID/DATAFILE/PROD_01         13 PROD_01                            32767.9844
.1354.1133455263
```

**ADD DATAFILE IN TABLESPACE.**

```
ALTER TABLESPACE PROD_01 ADD DATAFILE '+DATA' SIZE 2G AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1G MAXSIZE 32767M;
```

Issue got fixed now !!